# Does HMS analytics supports for fragments?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I want to implement the HMS analytics in the fragment does HMS Analytics Kit supports fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer to your question is: yes, Analytics Kit supports fragments.

The static methods in [HiAnalytics](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-References-V5/android-api-hianalytics-0000001050707170-V5) need either an Activity or a Context instance, both of which are provided by a Fragment. Check out [this implementation tutorial](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-accessing-0000001050161888-V5).